# Column name formatting in KableExtra in R

Tags: r, word-wrap, kableextra, italics

Latex command are not formatting the column names as I intended.

```
library(kableExtra)
kable(test,"latex", col.names = c('Mean','\\textit{N}' ,'Strongly\nDisagree','Disagree','Neither Agree\norDisagree','Agree','Strongly\nAgree'))
```

The output I am getting is:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xvl7lfh94bl2274/Kable%20Table.PNG?dl=0

I have tried both latex commands and R-markdown commands.

The N should be italicized and Strong disagree, Neither Agree or Disagree, and Strongly Agree should be broken up on two lines.

Comment: You will need to check out the `linebreak()` function in `kableExtra`.  Also, you will need to add `escape = FALSE` to `kable(...)`

Comment: I got it to work!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Please post your solution and reproducible example as an answer so that others may learn from it.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test_data <- data.frame(Mean = runif(5, 3.71, 7.72),
                        N = sample(57:59, 5, replace = TRUE),
                        sd = c(1, rep(0, 4)),
                        d = rep(1, 5),
                        naod = sample(1:4, 5, replace = TRUE),
                        a = sample(5:12, 5, replace = TRUE),
                        sa = sample(37:44, 5, replace = TRUE))

kable(test_data,"latex" ,booktabs=T,
      align="c",
      col.names=linebreak(c('Mean','\\textit{N}' ,'Strongly\n Disagree','Disagree','Neither Agree\n or Disagree','Agree','Strongly\n Agree')),
      row.names = T,escape=F) %>%
  row_spec(0,align = "c")
```